# Making a button with dynamic background color in React Native

Tags: dynamic, react-native, styles

I made a React Native component that wraps up a Touchable element and takes in a theme color as a prop. Different themes make the button background color different. Right now I have an if statement in the render function that checks the prop and selects the style accordingly:

```
render() {
  var bgColor;
  if (this.props.theme === 'blue') {
    bgColor = styles.blueBg;
  }
  else if (this.props.theme === 'red') {
    bgColor = styles.redBg;
  }

  //  (...)

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button, bgColor]}>
    {/* ... */}
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ...
  blueBg: {
    backgroundColor = 'blue'
  },
  redBg: {
    backgroundColor = 'red'
  },
});
```

Is this the proper way of doing this? Should I move my if statements somewhere else? Is there another approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Rather than doing this what about :

super(props);
this.state = {bgColor : (this.props.theme === 'blue')? styles.blueBg : styles.redBg};

render(){
return (
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button,this.state.bgColor]}>
    {/* ... */}
    </TouchableHighlight>

)
}
```

Comment: Okay, it seems reasonable to have the theme set on initialization, since render may be called many times. There would be more themes, though, so I wouldn't use a ternary operator.